# What is the Python way of getting a list in from another file and class function

Tags: python, arrays, list, class, return

As a C# programmer I'm learning python and one of the issues is what is the pythons way of handing lists back and forth. Maybe I don't know what its called so I am missing the tutorials.

I want to create a list of lists and use that in a main program but access the complexity of that creation in another file and access that as a function from the main program flow as an import.

Maybe it's a constructor of somekind? A list of Tuples? Better to do this as an array?

It seems that there are lists that are not able to iterate through, and the whole passing classes back and forth.

```py
class TestPattern:
    def __init__(self,csvFileName,chartTitle,chartName):
        self.csvFileName =  csvFileName
        self.chartTitle = chartTitle
        self.chartName = chartName

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}, {1}, {2}".format(self.csvFileName,self.chartTitle,self.chartName)

class TestPatternEntries:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add(self, TestPattern):
        self.items.append(TestPattern)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.__items.__iter__()


patterns = TestPatternEntries()
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\Lorentz.csv','Lorentz ','Lorentz'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\CosineDecAmpFreqInc.csv','Cosine Dec Amp Freq Inc ','CosineDecAmpFreqInc'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\CosineDecAmpFreqInc.csv','Cosine Dec Amp Freq Inc ','CosineDecAmpFreqInc'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\ExponentialDecayTenWaves.csv','Exponential Decay ','ExponentialDecayTenWaves'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\ExponentialRiseTenWaves.csv','Exponential Rise ','ExponentialRiseTenWaves'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\LinearFall.csv','LinearFall ','LinearFall'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\LinearRise.csv','Linear Rise ','LinearRise'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\Multitone.csv','Multitone ','Multitone'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\Pulse10Waves.csv','Pulse ','Pulse'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\Pulse10WavesInverted.csv','Pulse Inverted ','Pulse10WavesInverted'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\RandomSamples.csv','Random Noise ','RandomSamples'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\SinFiveWaves.csv','Five Sin Waves ','FiveSinWaves'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\SinFourtyWaves.csv','Fourty Sin Waves ','SinFourtyWaves'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\SweepOneToFive.csv','Sweep 1:5 ','SweepOneToFive'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\SyncPattern.csv','Sync Pattern ','SyncPattern'))
patterns.add(TestPattern('CSVTestPatterns\TriangleTenWaves.csv','Triangle Waveform','TriangleTenWaves'))

for item in patterns.items:
    print(item)
```

So whats the catch in what is in the code below that I am missing? Is there a good tutorial on handing lists back and forth from local code in other files? Maybe I missed it? Just want to get a full list back that one could iterate through or access by the place in the list.

Comment: Is there more to `TestPatternEntries`? There's nothing wrong with just using a list to store multiple `TestPatterns`: `patterns = [TestPattern(), TestPattern(), ...]`.

Comment: Should be `return self.items.__iter__()` not `return self.__items.__iter__()`.  Could be simply `return iter(self.items)`.  Since `TestPatternEntries` is iterable you can just do `for item in patterns:print(item)`.

Comment: But as @chepner says, unless `TestPatternEntries` does something special it doesn't make much sense to create a class.  Just use a list, that's what it's for.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. Have cleaned it up and returned the list with def get_list(); return patterns. Seems to work!